# Gridview click header row doesn't select data for update or delete

Tags: c#, datagridview, onclick, header-row

I've found a curious situation working with gridview.

Selecting one header row on the gridview, supposedly should select the data fields and pass them to the Winform fields that allow editing to Update the record or Delete the record.

Apparently the same code produces different results.

Any idea what's happening and how to correct the situation?

Thank you.

The working code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace InsertUpdateDeleteDemo
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record
        int ID = 0;
        DataTable dt;
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }
        private void txt_SearchName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee where FirstName like '" + txt_SearchName.Text + "%'", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
            ClearData();
        }
        //Insert Data
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_First_Name.Text != "" && txt_Last_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")
            {
                txt_SearchName.Text = "";
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_Employee(FirstName,LastName,State) values(@FirstName,@state)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_First_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_Last_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
                ClearData();
                DisplayData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
            }
        }
        //Display Data in DataGridView
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            adapt=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee",con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        //Clear Data
        private void ClearData()
        {
            txt_First_Name.Text = "";
            txt_Last_Name.Text = "";
            txt_State.Text = "";
            ID = 0;
        }
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            txt_First_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_Last_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txt_State.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_First_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Employee set FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,State=@state where ID=@id", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_First_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_Last_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
        }
        //Delete Record
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ID!=0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tbl_Employee where ID=@id",con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
            }
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

        private void txt_First_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_Last_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_State_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Two pieces of similar code. In first view, one works, the other doesn't.

When clicking gridview header row, the data is not selected and passed to the Winform fields.

Any hint why?

The non-working code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Banco_de_Imagens_Beatriz
{
    public partial class EcranDiagnostico : Form
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=Posto0;Initial Catalog=Banco_Imagens;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12QWaszx";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Posto0;Initial Catalog=Banco_Imagens;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12QWaszx");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record
        int iddiag = 0;
        DataTable dt;
        public EcranDiagnostico()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }
        private void txt_SearchName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag where nome_diag like '" + txt_SearchName.Text + "%'", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
            ClearData();
        }
        //Insert Data
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_NomeDiag.Text != "" && txt_DescrDiag.Text != "")
            {
                txt_SearchName.Text = "";
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tb_diag(nome_diag,descr_diag) values(@nome_diag,@descr_diag)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_diag", txt_NomeDiag.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr_diag", txt_DescrDiag.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo inserido com sucesso.");
                ClearData();
                DisplayData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não introduziu dados. Introduza os dados que pretende.");
            }
        }
        //Display Data in DataGridView
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag", con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        //Clear Data
        private void ClearData()
        {
            txt_NomeDiag.Text = "";
            txt_DescrDiag.Text = "";
            iddiag = 0;
        }
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            iddiag = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            txt_NomeDiag.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_DescrDiag.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_NomeDiag.Text != "" && txt_DescrDiag.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tb_diag set nome_diag=@nome_diag,descr_diag=@descr_diag where iddiag=@iddiag", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddiag", iddiag);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_diag", txt_NomeDiag.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr_diag", txt_DescrDiag.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo actualizado com sucesso.");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não seleccionou nenhum registo. Seleccione o registo a actualizarr.");
            }
        }
        //Delete Record
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (iddiag != 0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tb_diag where iddiag=@iddiag", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddiag", iddiag);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo eliminado com sucesso.");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não seleccionou nenhum registo. Seleccione o registo a eliminar");
            }
        }
        private void EcranDiagnostico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: esta linha de código carrega dados na tabela 'dataSet_Tabela_Diagnostico.tb_diag'. Você pode movê-la ou removê-la conforme necessário.
            //this.tb_diagTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet_Tabela_Diagnostico.tb_diag);
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

        private void txt_NomeDiag_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_DescrDiag_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the RowHeaderMouseClick subscribed to your handler?

Comment: Can you elaborate, Rob?

Comment: Please read [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you for your recommandation Asif.Ali. In the future I will try to stick to it.